# Link issues with cmake/make

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, linker

I'm new to cmake/make so I'm trying to do a simple compilation with include and lib directories as well as a library to link to the main file.

My directory structure looks like this

```
PROJECTDIRECTORY/
 main.c
 CMAKELISTS.txt
 include/
   add.h
 lib/
   add.a
 build/
```

My main.c contains

```c
#include <add.h>

int main(void)
{
    add(5,10);
    return 0;
}
```

My add.h contains

```c
int add(int x,int y);
```

And my add.a is a static library which I compiled from add.c which contains the implementation.

Finally in my CMakeLists.txt I have

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6)
project(addproject)

add_executable(addproject main.c)

include_directories(include)

link_directories(lib)

target_link_libraries(addproject add.a)
```

Then when I run cmake . , it generates the makefile correctly.

But when I run make, I receive a linker error

```
Scanning dependencies of target addproject
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/addproject.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable addproject
ld: library not found for -ladd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [addproject] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/addproject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Stating it can't find library for add? Even though I set library_directories in cmake..
Can someone help me fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `add.c`? You shouldn't be linking to library _files_, but rather to library _targets_, especially if you created them yourself.

Comment: @AlexReinking Well I was testing with a library file. So add.c isn't there because I've already compiled add.a into add.c and I wanted to see if I could link it with cmake..

Comment: then the answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41909627/2137996

Comment: Thank you that does answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you compiled `add.c` into `add.a` yourself, you should just do everything with targets in CMake. You don't say where `add.c` is, but I'm going to assume it's in `lib`. Here's what you should write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(addproject)

add_library(add lib/add.c)
target_include_directories(add PUBLIC include)

add_executable(addproject main.c)
target_link_libraries(addproject PRIVATE add)
```

Now that CMake manages both parts of the build, it will derive correct compiler flags for `addproject` when linking to `add`. Note that "PUBLIC" properties *propagate* to their linkees. So because `addproject` links to `add`, it will receive the include directories for `add`.

In new CMake code, *never* use directory functions like `include_directories` and `link_directories`. They're the decade-old way of doing things. They're brittle, error-prone, and have weird behaviors you don't want me to explain. Use the `target_*` functions.

Comment: i guess you should type add.c instead of acc.c

Comment: Yup. Fat-fingered it.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. That's fine I was doing it with add.c is there any way I can link with add.a instead of telling it to compile add.c into add.a then linking?

Comment: I would like you to keep this answer in case anyone comes across it and wants to do it with source files instead of already compiled library files. Thank you!